# Sending failed: Protocol Error while setting up nullmailer

Tags: smtp, amazon-ses

I'm trying to set up nullmailer (1.13) to send to AWS SES and failing. Here are the contents of my `remotes` file:

```
email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com smtp --starttls --port=465 --user=AKIA.. --pass=..
```

And here's the error in `/var/log/mail.err`.

```
Mar 16 01:26:05 server nullmailer[7663]: smtp: Failed:
Mar 16 01:26:05 server nullmailer[29064]: Sending failed:  Protocol error
```

I've tried with and without `--starttls`. I also tried `--ssl` [as this blog recommended](http://www.e-artspace.com/home/blog/66-integrating-nulmailer-with-amazon-ses).

Comment: `--user=AKIA...` is probably wrong.  You don't use your access key ID & secret for SMTP with SES:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-credentials.html

Comment: SES SMTP credentials look like that- "SMTP username is the same as their AWS Access Key ID". @Michael-sqlbot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stumbled across my own question and figured it out. The testing shell script here really helped, and running nullmail-send by hand showed me that `ubuntu@localhost` was the FROM address, which was rejected by SES.

http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/nullmailer/

Besides the protocol error, I was getting a config failure that eventually I discovered was a permissions problem. Here's that error:

```
Dec 10 19:59:46 irc nullmailer[9011]: Could not load the config
```

So, a couple changes:

- nullmailer on ubuntu runs as the `mail` user, so it can't read the `/etc/nullmailer/remotes` that was owned by root and mod 600 for root. So: `chown mail:mail /etc/nullmailer/*`.
- Fixed the `ubuntu@localhost`, probably from cron/system mails, by adding my domain in `/etc/nullmailer/defaulthost`.
- `remotes` also needed `--ssl` on it to talk to port 465 in SES.